# Compile GDAL with GEOS

Tags: c++, gdal, geos

How can I compile GDAL with GEOS support enabled? I managed to compile it in release only but I need a debug dll too. Is there a Tutorial somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

Nothing too special about it.

Assuming your GEOS is installed system-wide: `./configure --with-geos`

If not, you will need to set `CFLAGS`/`LDFLAGS` before